# How do I boot from ISO file stored on hard disk?

Tags: system-installation, iso, bootable

I know that I can create/burn bootable CD/DVD or live USB and can boot/install from it. But suppose I am currently running GNU/Linux and I've ISO file of another GNU/Linux that I want to install on my hard disk, then Can I directly boot from ISO from hard disk and try/install that GNU/Linux operating system?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, you can accomplish this by adding a menu entry to the `GRUB` boot loader menu.

You can add a custom GRUB menu entry by editing `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`,

**Example of custom menuentry**:

```
 exec tail -n +3 $0
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.  

menuentry "Trisquel ISO" {
        set isofile="/Operating_Systems/Trisquel_7.0_i686/trisquel_7.0_i686.iso"
        loopback loop (hd0,5)$isofile
        linux (loop)/casper/vmlinuz boot=casper iso-scan/filename=$isofile quiet splash
        initrd (loop)/casper/initrd
}
```

**Instruction & Explanation:**

1. The command [**`set`**](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#set) is used for storing the path of the ISO file into a variable, here `isofile`.
2. [**`loopback`**](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#loopback) is used to make a device from a file system image. In order to do that, it is necessary to specify the device and image file. Here we used `(hd0,5)$isofile` in which `(hd0,5)` represents the **fifth** partition of the disk.

   - Points to note: In `(hd0,5)` , 
     1<sup>st</sup> digit represents the device number which starts from `0` (here : 0 = 1<sup>st</sup> device) and
     2<sup>nd</sup> digit represents the partition number which starts from `1` (here 5 = 5<sup>th</sup> partition).
     That means `/dev/sda5`
   - And variable `$isofile` has the path of the ISO file. So, finally it becomes `(hd0,5)/Operating_Systems/Trisquel_7.0_i686/trisquel_7.0_i686.iso`.
   - For more information, visit : [How to specify devices](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#Device-syntax) and [files](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#File-name-syntax).
3. [**`linux`**](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#linux) command is used to load Linux kernel ([vmlinuz](http://www.linfo.org/vmlinuz.html)) from file. Put the path of Linux kernel in the ISO.

   - Read/extract the content of ISO to get the path of kernel example:

     ```
      $ 7z l trisquel_7.0_i686.iso | grep vmlinu
      2014-10-29 21:41:43 .....      5841680      5841680  casper/vmlinuz
      2014-11-03 00:45:09 .....      5844176      5844176  casper/vmlinuz.netinst
     ```

     so, `/casper/vmlinuz` was used here.
4. [**`initrd`**](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html#initrd) command is used to load an initial ramdisk for a Linux kernel image, and set the appropriate parameters in the Linux setup area in memory.

   - [initrd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initrd) is a scheme for loading a temporary root file system into memory. Put the path of `initrd` in the ISO.
   - Read/extract the content of ISO to get the path of `initrd`:

     ```
     $ 7z l trisquel_7.0_i686.iso | grep initrd
     2014-11-03 00:45:19 .....     16851900     16851900  casper/initrd
     2014-11-03 00:45:09 .....      9398592      9398592  casper/initrd.netinst
     ```
5. The additional parameter such as `boot=casper iso-scan/filename=$isofile noprompt noeject` may be specific to a GNU/Linux distribution and vary for another family of Linux. You can find some configurations for different family/distribution from [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20170718204158/https://git.marmotte.net/git/glim/tree/grub2).

   Note: Some distributions use `initrd.gz` or `initrd.lz` depending upon the algorithm/compression used.

After editing `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`, GRUB needs to be updated by `update-grub2` command. Upon rebooting, you will find the custom menuentry you've added on the GRUB screen. And you may use the Live environment of a GNU/Linux distribution.

In order to perform installation from ISO, installer may need to unmount any mounted partitions; i.e. say another system is mounted at `/isodevice`, then you can `umount -l /isodevice`.

Comment: Wow, I'm impressed...I would have thought it would be impossible, since installing a new OS often involves reformatting partitions, which could include the partition your ISO file is stored on.

Comment: Your samples uses GRUB2. Centos 6 uses GRUB1 (grub legacy) and above examples doesn't work.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/ISOBoot