# Install other linux distributions on same machine after installing Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation, dual-boot

I have new machine and i install Ubuntu.
I want to install other Linux distributions also - and i want to be able to choose on the startup witch Linux distributions to run.

I install 'grub' on my machine ( thru Ubuntu ) and now i don't know how to continue .. what to do next ?

This is my first time on Linux - so if someone know what i suppose to do now - please be patient and explain in detail

thanks.

Comment: Unless you want different kernels, you might consider using a chroot for the different distros.

Comment: ok .. .now please explain :) because i didn't understand nothing

Comment: Just Install other distro (by burning iso to disk/usb-stick or by [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/251079/66803) way) similar to that you've installed Ubutnu (don't touch the partition where current system is installed). You'll be able to choose which to boot from at start-up (by grub).

Comment: Ugh, I was going to give a lengthy explanation, but decided against it because that would be crazy without knowing more about what you want and the tech. spec.s.  Just look into 'gparted' and 'hard drive partitioning'.  Gentoo also has a manual that explains disk partitioning very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have installed Ubuntu using a usb drive and hence you are familiar with creating bootable USB drive. If not refer to [this.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick)

Step 1. Write the ISO of the distro you want to install to a USB drive

Step 2. During installation most distro will automatically detect the existing Ubuntu installation. Consequently they will give option to install the new distro 'side-by-side' to Ubuntu or you do it manually. Select the option you are most comfortable with.

Step 3. Complete installation, reboot.

Step 4. On boot up, a screen will come up that will have installed operating systems as a list and you can choose. Mostly it waits for 10seconds for a user input, otherwise boots into a default distro.
Step 5. You can edit the Grub file to change the boot time behavior (wait time, default distro etc)

Hope this helps,